# Why is flutter giving me an exit error 66 after pub get?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

After updating to latest flutter version "2.10.3" flutter pub get gives me an exit error 66.

**Here is the output:**

```
> flutter pub get
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/opt/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine".
Running "flutter pub get" in iot_door_security...                       
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/opt/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine".)
```

I am using the latest MacbookPro M1 Pro running *Monterey 12.3*

I tried flutter clean, which just removes cached files and also tried manually deleting /Users/<username>/.pub-cache/

Any suggestions? Is there a way to downgrade to a earlier version of flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there is a pubspec.yaml file in the directory you are running the command from.

Comment: Yes, the file is there in the root project folder. But the output error message suggests it checks somewhere else in the flutter runnable folder, idk. why ?

Comment: Are you running the command from the console?

Comment: Yes and my working directory is the root folder of the flutter project. This happened after I updated flutter on top of that MacOS updated to the latest version as well, I guess the whole updating process must have damaged something and is connected to this issue.

Comment: Maybe try creating a new flutter project somewhere and running flutter pub get in it to see if the issue is universal or just in the one project

Answer (score 0):

I realised I had installed flutter bins in **/opt/** which after the update permissions got messy and that's where the problem originated from.

I installed flutter in my **home folder**, everything is working fine now!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).